# How to setup security on a document library with the following requirements:

Tags: document-library, item-level-permissions, sharepoint-permissions

We have a Knowledge Base with content that is fed from document libraries located in different site collections.  Each library will have a designated few that can contribute content.  Those individuals should be able to upload, edit, and delete their content, but ONLY their content.  The content should be readable to all and accessible via search.

How can I set permissions so that you can only edit and delete your content, yet all content should be readable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, you want to assign permission at document level when uploading a document.

Per my test, there is no OOTB way to assign permission when uploading. You’ll need to create a custom solution to do that.

As a workaround, you can set permission after uploading the documents.

First, you need to stop the document inheriting permission from the document library. Then assign the document with proper permission. Here are the specific steps:

Choose the `document >Files tab > Shared With > Advanced >Stop Inheriting Permission > Grant Permissions`.

If there are several documents with same permission, you can put them into a folder and assign the folder with proper permission.